# Correct usage of an MVC pattern in web applictaion

Tags: javascript, mvc, ajax, knockout.js

I have a method in my controller (`GetAllPatients`/`EnrollmentQueue`) which does return the correct data (an array of `ViewModel`s). I'm new in Knockout.js, so it's hard for me to understand how to display this data correctly. Here is my HTML:

```
<table data-bind="visible: Patients().length > 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Assigned to
            </th>
            <th>
                Follow up Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Follow up
            </th>
            <th>
                Patient Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Foundation
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Patients">
        <tr>
            <td><label data-bind="text:AssignedTo().ItemName"></label></td>
            <td> <label data-bind="text: FollowUpDate "></label></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Foundation"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:  PatientName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: FollowupItem().ItemName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function PatientViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.FollowUpDate = ko.observable(new Date());
        self.FollowupItem = ko.observable("");
        self.PatientName = ko.observable("");
        self.Foundation = ko.observable("");
        self.AssignedTo = ko.observable("");
        self.DoctorName = ko.observable("");
        self.Id = ko.observable(0);

        var PatientInfo = {
            FollowUpDate: self.FollowUpDate,
            FollowupItem: self.FollowUpItems,
            PatientName: self.PatientName,
            Foundation: self.Foundation,
            AssignedTo: self.AssignedTo
        };

        self.PatientInfo = ko.observable();
        self.Patients = ko.observableArray();

        self.FollowUpDateFilter = ko.observable("");
        self.FollowupItemFilter = ko.observable("");
        self.PatientNameFilter = ko.observable("");
        self.FoundationFilter = ko.observable("");
        self.AssignedToFilter = ko.observable("");

        var searchInfo =
        {
            FollowUpDateFilter: self.FollowUpDateFilter,
            FollowupItemFilter: self.FollowupItemFilter,
            PatientNameFilter: self.PatientNameFilter,
            FoundationFilter: self.FoundationFilter,
            AssignedToFilter: self.AssignedToFilter
        };
        self.filter = function () {
            var  modelToSend = {
                FollowUpDateFilter: searchInfo.FollowUpDateFilter(),
                FollowupItemFilter: searchInfo.FollowupItemFilter()?searchInfo.FollowupItemFilter().ItemName():"",
                PatientNameFilter: searchInfo.PatientNameFilter(),
                FoundationFilter: searchInfo.FoundationFilter() ? searchInfo.FoundationFilter().FoundationName() : "",
                AssignedToFilter: searchInfo.AssignedToFilter()?searchInfo.AssignedToFilter().DoctorsName():""
            };
            var viewModel = ko.toJS(modelToSend);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'GetAllPatients/EnrollmentQueue',
                cashe: false,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: ko.toJSON(viewModel),
                success: function (result) {
                    self.Patients(result);
                }
            });
        }
        self.AllDoctors = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["doctors"])));
        self.AllFollowUpItems = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["followUpItems"])));
        self.AllFoundations = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["foundation"])));
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllPatients", "Enrollment")',
            cashe: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                self.Patients(data);
            }
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var viewModel = new PatientViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
    }(window));
</script>
```

The page is calling the `GetAllPatients` method from `Controller` several times, and I'd like to simplify this. If you need more information, please ask.